# $f:(0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ concave implies $f$ bounded below?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a concave function such that $f$ is not indentically zero. It seems to me that the following statements are true:

I - For every $a>0$ fixed, $f_{|[a,\infty)}$ is bounded below by a positive constant depending on $a$,

II - $f$ cannot attain a maximum value in $[a,\infty)$.

Am I seeing things or those statements are true?

Thank you

Comment: Define concave. From the context it can be guessed but books never agree on this terminology.

Comment: Isn't always bounded below by zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is true, the second false.

Simple counterexample for the second, constants, or  $f(x) = \min \lbrace x, 1\rbrace$. If you meant *strictly* concave, the second is also true, because then $f$ must be strictly monotonically increasing.

The first is true because a concave function that is non-negative must be monotonic(ally nondecreasing), and cannot have a zero larger than $0$ unless it is identically $0$.

A concave function that is not monotonically non-decreasing cannot be bounded below:

Let $x_1 < x_2$ with $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$. Let $h = x_2 - x_1$ and $\delta = f(x_1) - f(x_2)$. Then

$$ f(x_1 + k\cdot h) \leqslant f(x_1) - k \cdot \delta\;, k \geqslant 1.$$

That is because by the definition of concaveness,

$$f(x_1) - \delta = f(x_2) = f\left(\frac{k-1}{k}x_1 + \frac{1}{k}(x_1 + k\cdot h)\right) \geqslant \frac{k-1}{k}f(x_1) + \frac{1}{k}f(x_1 + k\cdot h)$$

Thus (subtracting the first summand of the right hand side)

$$ \frac{1}{k}f(x_1) - \delta \geqslant \frac{1}{k}f(x_1 + k \cdot h) \iff f(x_1) - k\cdot \delta \geqslant f(x_1 + k\cdot h). $$

By assumption $\delta > 0$, so $f$ is not bounded below.

Geometrically, concaveness means the slope of the graph is monotonically non-increasing ($f'' \leqslant 0$, if by $f''$ we understand the distribution derivative, if the classical derivative doesn't exist), thus once the slope is negative, it remains so, and can only become more negative, never less.

Comment: Sorry for II, I want the function defined in $[a,\infty)$ too.

Comment: The example I gave is defined on $[0, \infty)$. It's $f(x) = x,\, x \leqslant 1$, $f(x) = 1,\, x \geqslant 1$. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing, you are right. Coould you explain me why a concave function non-negative must be monotonic?

Comment: Sure, I'll expand. Will take a few minutes.