# Does $y'=|y|^a$ have any global solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, initial-value-problems

Assume the differential equation

$$
y'=|y|^a
$$
My intuition tells me that since it involves an absolute value, there might not be any solutions defined everywhere, except for the case $a=0$, where $y(x)=x+c$.

To show this, let
$$
f(y)=|y|^a$$

$\bullet\,$For $a<0$:

$f$ is not defined for $y=0$ plus it's not bounded

$\bullet\,$ For $a=0$:
$$y'=1 \iff y(x)=x+c, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
$\bullet\,$ For $a>0$:

$f$ is defined $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, but it's not bounded

Can we thus conclude that the only global solution of $y'=|y|^a$ is $y(x)=x+c$?

Comment: What do you mean by a global solution? Should $y(x)$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Exactly

Comment: For $a=1$ you can take $y = e^{x+c}$.

Comment: You consider $y' = f(y)$ with $f(y) = \lvert y \rvert^a$. The problem with $f$ is that $f(0)$ is undefined for $a \le 0$ (recall that not only $1/0$, but also $0^0$ is undefined). For $a=0$ you may of course *interpret* your definition as $f(y) \equiv 1$ (in which case you get your solution $y(x) = x + c$), but note $f(y) \equiv 1$ does not really agree with the original definition.

So for $a \le 0$ solutions $y(x)$ must satisfy $y(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: So, technically there are no global solutions for $a\leq 0$?

Comment: No for $a=0$, but I am not sure for $a < 0$ (although I doubt it). For example, if $a=-1$, then $y(x) =\sqrt{2x}$ is a solution on $(0,\infty)$, but it is not differentiable in $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have summarised some of the information that has already been stated and made an attempt to complete the answer.

I believe that your question may be rephrased as follows: given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ does there exist $y:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(Dy)(t) = |y(t)|^a$ (1) for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Remark: it is assumed that $0^0$ is not defined.

Consider four cases (the first two cases are not necessary to answer your question, but it is always useful to exhibit closed-form analytic solutions when they exist):

**Case I**: $a = 1$. If $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $y(t)=ce^{\mathsf{sgn}(c) t}$ is a solution of (1) on $\mathbb{R}$ (this case is not necessary: see Case III).

**Case II**: $0 < a < 1$. Then $y(t)=sgn(t)(1-a)^{\frac{1}{1-a}}(sgn(t)t)^{\frac{1}{1-a}}$ is a solution of (1) on $\mathbb{R}$ (this case is not necessary: see Case III) - of course, other solutions may be obtained using the expression above.

**Case III**: $a > 1$. Then $y(t) = 0$ is a solution of (1) on $\mathbb{R}$ (of course, $y(t) = 0$ is also a solution for $0 < a \leq 1$).

**Case IV**: $a \leq 0$. Suppose that $y(t)$ is a solution of (1) on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $y(t)\neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Given that $(Dy)(t)=|y(t)|^a$, $(Dy)(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. However, then $y$ must be an increasing function.  Therefore, by differentiability of $y$, either $y(t) < 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ or $y(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $y(t) < 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(Dy)(t)=(-y(t))^a$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, the second derivative exists and is given by $(D^2 y)(t)=-a(-y(t))^{2a-1}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Under assumptions $a \leq 0$ and $y(t) < 0$, $ 0 \leq (D^2 y)(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $y(t)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $y(t)$ is constant ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091/show-bounded-and-convex-function-on-mathbb-r-is-constant)). However, $y(t)$ is also an increasing function. Thus, a contradiction is reached and, therefore, $y(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $y(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, consider a function $q(t)$ such that $q(t)=y(-t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $q(t)>0$, Also, $(Dq)(t)=-q(t)^a=-(y(-t))^a$ and $(D^2q)(t)=aq(t)^{2a-1}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $(Dq)(t) < 0$ and $(D^2q)(t) \leq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $q$ is decreasing and concave on $\mathbb{R}$. However, in this case, it cannot be bounded below ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429302/f0-infty-to-0-infty-concave-implies-f-bounded-below/429309)). Thus, by contradiction, if $a \leq 0$, then (1) does not have any global solutions on $\mathbb{R}$.

In conclusion, if $a > 0$, then there always exists at least one global solution of (1). Otherwise, (1) does not have any global solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that $f$ be bounded. When $a=1/2$ you can use $y(x)=(x^2/4) \mathrm{sgn\,} x$, for example and you can also translate $x\mapsto x+c$ to get other solutions. Also don't forget Cauchy-Lipschitz fails, so $y\equiv0$ is a solution too.